# Android device screen doesn't turn on

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, wakelock

I was developing an app to show videos. A BroadCastReceiver receives a AC_PPWER_CONNECTED an starts the VideoViewActivity. I can hear the sound of the Video, but the screen is off, either i want to turn it on with a wahe lock.

Following Code doesn't work.

```
package org.adem.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.adem.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.KeyguardManager;
import android.app.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
        OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = VideoViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int mVideoWidth;
    private int mVideoHeight;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Bundle extras;
    private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
    private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
    private ArrayList<String> pathList;
    private int videoQueueSize;
    private int currentPosition;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    KeyguardLock lock;

    /**
     * 
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);


        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        lock.disableKeyguard();

        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    }

    private void playVideo() {

        if ("".equals(pathList.get(currentPosition))) {
            // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
            Toast.makeText(
                    VideoViewActivity.this,
                    "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity, "
                    + "and set the path variable to your media file path."
                    + " Your media file must be stored on sdcard.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        } else {
            try {

                // Create a new media player and set the listeners
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(pathList.get(currentPosition));
                mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);

    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        if (currentPosition >= videoQueueSize) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoViewActivity.this, "Video Playback finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        } else {
            playVideo();
            currentPosition++;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");
        if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");
            return;
        }
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;
        mVideoWidth = width;
        mVideoHeight = height;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;
        if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {
            startVideoPlayback();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");

    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
        pathList = extras.getStringArrayList("Path");
        currentPosition = 0;
        videoQueueSize = pathList.size();
        if (!wl.isHeld()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated - wl.acquire()");
            wl.acquire();
        }
        playVideo();
        Log.d(TAG, pathList.get(currentPosition));
        currentPosition++;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseMediaPlayer();
        doCleanUp();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    private void doCleanUp() {
        mVideoWidth = 0;
        mVideoHeight = 0;
        mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;
        mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;
        if (wl.isHeld()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doCleanUp - wl.release()");
            wl.release();
        }
    }

    private void startVideoPlayback() {
        Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");
        holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

What is wron with the wake lock command. What i'm wondering is, that the screen turns on when wl.release was called at the ent of the of the doCleanUp method.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below Snippet :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "WakeClock");
```

Comment: Thanks, you save my day! Do i still need
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);